# Obtaining the sense of a verb of a given sentece using verbnet

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

Using nltk and verbnet, it is possible to get all the senses of the verb using

```
verbnet.classid()
```

But this function returns all of the senses of the verb. In a given sentence only one verbsense is used. Has anyone ever made progress into determining the verbsense of a given sentence?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a research task called 'Verb sense disambiguation' or 'verb class disambiguation'. See relevant papers: [2008](http://linguistica.sns.it/Workshop_verb/papers/Chen_verb2010_submission_11.pdf), [2010](http://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~arir/vn.pdf), [2012](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/P12-1028) (they use verbnet as well).

State-of-the-art approaches are often based on supervised learning and use for train/test [SemLink dataset](http://verbs.colorado.edu/semlink/) (see corresponding [paper](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/W13-5503)); features are usually based on syntactic parsing, lexical representations and contexts.